# How to retrieve the unicode decimal representation of the chars in a string containing hindi text?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, ascii, hindi

I am using visual studio 2010 in c# for converting text into unicodes. Like i have a string abc= "मेरा" .
there are 4 characters in this string. i need all the four unicode characters.
Please help me.

Comment: See http://unicodelookup.com/#मेरा/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write a code like `string abc= "मेरा";`, you already have it as Unicode (specifically, UTF-16), so you don't have to convert anything. If you want to access the singular characters, you can do that using normal index: e.g. `abc[1]` is `े` (DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN E).

If you want to see the numeric representations of those characters, just cast them to integers. For example

```
abc.Select(c => (int)c)
```

gives the sequence of numbers 2350, 2375, 2352, 2366. If you want to see the hexadecimal representation of those numbers, use `ToString()`:

```
abc.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("x4"))
```

returns the sequence of strings "092e", "0947", "0930", "093e".

Note that when I said numeric representations, I actually meant their encoding using UTF-16. For characters in the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), this is the same as their Unicode code point. The vast majority of used characters lie in BMP, including those 4 Hindi characters presented here.

If you wanted to handle characters in other planes too, you could use code like the following.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(abc);

int codePointCount = bytes.Length / 4;

int[] codePoints = new int[codePointCount];

for (int i = 0; i < codePointCount; i++)
    codePoints[i] = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, i * 4);
```

Since UTF-32 encodes all (21-bit) code points directly, this will give you them. (Maybe there is a more straightforward solution, but I haven't found one.)

Comment: this is what i was looking for. please tell me how the abc.Select(c => (int)c)
can be used to get the 4 values in a variable.

Comment: @Deepak, what do you mean? The result of that is a sequence with those 4 values. If you want to put them in a variable, just do `var chars = abc.Select(c => (int)c);` like with any other code.

Comment: You can then for example use `foreach` and `Console.WriteLine()` to write them out to console.

Comment: abc.Select() gives an error, 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Select'...

How are you able to run this code?

Comment: @ePandit You're probably missing using System.Linq; at the top of your C# file.

Comment: @svick, It seems that using System.Linq requires .NET FW 3.5 or later. My target framework is set to 2.0

Answer (score 3):

Since a .Net char *is a* Unicode character (at least, for the BMP code point), you can simply enumerate all characters in a string:

```
var abc = "मेरा";

foreach (var c in abc)
{
    Console.WriteLine((int)c);
}
```

resulting in

```
2350
2375
2352
2366
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(abc)
```

that will return your unicode values.

Comment: thanks but can u give me the full code so that i can store it in a hexadecimal no.

Comment: You're wrong. This will not return “Unicode values”, by which I assume you mean Unicode code points. This will return they bytes which represent given string in UTF-8.

Comment: please anyone help me to get unicode values as for म the value is 2350 in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are trying to convert files from a legacy encoding into Unicode:**

Read the file, supplying the correct encoding of the source files, then write the file using the desired Unicode encoding scheme.

```
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\MyFile.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISCII")))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\MyConvertedFile.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

**If you are looking for a mapping of Devanagari characters to the Unicode code points:**

You can find the chart at the [Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/) website [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0900.pdf).

Note that Unicode code points are traditionally written in hexidecimal. So rather than the decimal number 2350, the code point would be written as U+092E, and it appears as 092E on the code chart.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the string `s = मेरा` then you already have the answer.

This string contains four code points in the BMP which in UTF-16 are represented by 8 bytes. You can access them by index with `s[i]`, with a `foreach` loop etc.

If you want the underlying 8 bytes you can access them as so:

```
string str = @"मेरा";
byte[] arr = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes(str);
```

Comment: The string contains 4 code points and it's represented as 4 `char`s or 8 bytes. Your code (when fixed) returns an array of 8 bytes.

Comment: @svick I can only see 2 code points. Can you explain where 4 comes from?

Comment: @svick It seems my Hindi is not very good!! I've corrected my answer.

Comment: yes, when rendered, you can only see two glyphs. That's because the string contains two non-spacing marks: [U+0947](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/947/index.htm) and [U+093E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/93E/index.htm).