# How do I read characters in a string as their UTF-32 decimal values?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, encoding

I have, for example, this Unicode string, which consists of the [Cyclone](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f300/index.htm) and the [Japanese Castle](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f3ef/index.htm) defined in C# and .NET, which uses UTF-16 for its CLR string encoding:

```
var value = "";
```

If you check this, you find very quickly that `value.Length = 4` because C# uses UTF-16 encoded strings, so for these reasons I can't just loop on each character and get its UTF-32 decimal value: `foreach (var character in value) result = (ulong)character;`. It begs the question, how can I get the UTF-32 decimal value for each character in any string?

Cyclone should be `127744` and Japanese Castle should be `127983`, but I am looking for a general answer that can take any C# string and always produce a UTF-32 decimal value out of each character inside of it.

I've even tried taking a look at [Char.ConvertToUtf32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.converttoutf32(v=vs.110).aspx), but this seems to be problematic if, for example:

```
var value = "ac";
```

This has a length of 6. So, how do I know when a new character begins? For example:

```
Char.ConvertToUtf32(value, 0)   97  int
Char.ConvertToUtf32(value, 1)   127744  int
Char.ConvertToUtf32(value, 2)   'Char.ConvertToUtf32(value, 2)' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'   int {System.ArgumentException}
Char.ConvertToUtf32(value, 3)   99  int
Char.ConvertToUtf32(value, 4)   127983  int
Char.ConvertToUtf32(value, 5)   'Char.ConvertToUtf32(value, 5)' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'   int {System.ArgumentException}
```

There is also the:

```
public static int ConvertToUtf32(
    char highSurrogate,
    char lowSurrogate
)
```

But for me to use this as well I need to figure out when I have surrogate pairs. How can you do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903113/how-to-retrieve-the-unicode-decimal-representation-of-the-chars-in-a-string-cont

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks, the accepted answer there will work but I was hoping there was a more elegant way of doing it in .NET.

Comment: sometimes the most elegant way look and or appears a bit complex.. in regards to code structure

Comment: @MethodMan That's fine by me. It may help the junior developers learn something new. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an extension method that illustrates one way to do it.  The idea is that you can loop through each character of the string, and use `char.ConvertToUtf32(string, index)` to get the unicode value.  If the returned value is larger than `0xFFFF`, then you know that the unicode value was composed of a set of surrogate characters, and you can adjust the index value accordingly to skip the 2nd surrogate character.

Extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetUnicodeCodePoints(this string s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        int unicodeCodePoint = char.ConvertToUtf32(s, i);
        if (unicodeCodePoint > 0xffff)
        {
            i++;
        }
        yield return unicodeCodePoint;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "ac";

    foreach(int unicodeCodePoint in s.GetUnicodeCodePoints())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(unicodeCodePoint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

**Solution 1**

```
string value = "";
byte[] rawUtf32AsBytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(value);
int[] rawUtf32 = new int[rawUtf32AsBytes.Length / 4];
Buffer.BlockCopy(rawUtf32AsBytes, 0, rawUtf32, 0, rawUtf32AsBytes.Length);
```

**Solution 2**

```
string value = "";
List<int> rawUtf32list = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsHighSurrogate(value[i]))
    {
        rawUtf32list.Add(Char.ConvertToUtf32(value[i], value[i + 1]));
        i++;
    }
    else
        rawUtf32list.Add((int)value[i]);
}
```

---

**Update:**

Starting with .NET Core 3.0 we have the `Rune` struct that represents a UTF32 character:

```
string value = "ac";
var runes = value.EnumerateRunes();

// writes a:97, :127744, c:99, :127983
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", runes.Select(r => $"{r}:{r.Value}")));
```

Comment: Also a great answer for using `Char.IsHighSurrogate`